# Extract proportion of raster by several rectangles

Tags: qgis, tiles, extract-by-mask

I have quite big raster and I 7 restangle polygons. What I need is to extract the raster so the result is 7 small TIFF tiles ideally using QGIS (possibly also ArcGIS but it's really slow here). Clip feature doesn't work properly as the result is one big black polygon.

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with `clip raster with polygon` in the SAGA-toolbox?

Comment: "Input layer has more than one band. Multiband layers are not supported by SAGA."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded and reprojected arbitrarily your image and, afterward, I created a layer with seven polygons; as it can be observed in following image:

[image]

With **raster -> Extraction -> Clip raster by mask layer** tool, I set following parameters (mask layer was loaded by default):

[image]

After click in Run button, result was as expected. A masked raster by seven polygon features.

[image]